# What's the difference between the <figure> tag and the <img> tag?

Tags: html

What is the difference between the `<figure>` tag and the `<img>` tag?

Comment: [This](https://www.learningjournal.guru/article/html5/html5-when-to-use-figure-tag/) will likely help you to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simple if you want to add an image in document you have to use **< img >** tag. The **< figure >** tag is used to display the image with self-explanatory about the image in the document.

Usually we saw like figure 6.1 1.3 in our text books. That is where figure tag should be used.

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp#:%7E:text=The%20tag%20specifies%20self,the%20flow%20of%20the%20document.) about figure tag.

Answer (score 0):

The figure tag in HTML5 is used to add self-contained content like illustrations, diagrams, photos, or codes listing in a document.
HTML img tag is used to add image or to set the background in the webpage/website.
please check this out:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-figure-img-tags-in-html/

Answer (score 0):

In short, like @Aathishithan G pointed out, it's similar to figure in the textbooks. Where a diagram or some sort of graphic explains, depicts, describes, proves aforementioned issue/topic/claim.

You totally could use, and that's what we used to, just `img` tag. However, `img` tag too generic, and computers could not differentiate when there was a decorative image or a content supporting, self-contained graphic. So, when we wrap images in the `figure` tag, browsers and search engines know whatever is inside, and it can be not just an image, is part of content context.

So, when you writing an article and you need to show a graph that proves your point, you use `figure`. Also, if you need to show a snippet of code for a problem you are describing, you use `figure`.
However, when you just need a nice photo at the head of your paragraph, to create or add an emotion to the content you can use `img`.

I guess a logic flow would be:
Is this image, quote or code self-contained or part of the context or point I am trying to make? then wrap your data in `figure`.
Is this image for decorative purposes or to augment or enhance emotional response? Then just use `img` alone.